# How to generate this vector in Octave/ MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a vector `centroids` of size `n` and a vector `points` of size `p` (both of these are actually `Vx3` matrices, where `V` is the number of points or centroids).

For any given point `pt` from `points`, I want to generate another vector of distances: the distance of `pt` from each centroid.

Is there any functional-programming style way of doing this? Something like this, maybe (Python-style):

```
distances = [ norm(pt - c) for c in centroids ]
```

If not, what is the nicest way for me to do this? I'm using Octave, but I added the [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) tag as well since the languages are quire similar (from what I can see, at least).

Comment: Have you looked at L2_distance: http://web.mit.edu/cocosci/isomap/code/L2_distance.m ? I think that might be helpful for sufficiently small matrices.

Comment: @Paul This is an assignment and I can't include other files than what is explicitly allowed. I wanted to know what is the shortest way to generate this list of distances. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a longer solution than g24l... I'm not sure which MATLAB versions `arrayfun` is valid for, so this should work on older ones:

```
pt = rand(1,3);
centroids = rand(2,3);
pt = repmat(pt, [size(centroids,1) 1]); % duplicate your point to vectorize
dists = sum((pt - centroids).^2,2)
```

All you'd have to do is wrap this in a function that takes a single `pt` and a matrix of `centroids` and you'd have your solution.

Comment: you should avoid repmat, it's slow , use `pt(ones(size_i_want, 1)` to get the same effect superfast

Comment: @g24l When I do `v = [1 2 3]; v(ones(3, 1))` in Octave I only get `1 1 1` and not `1 2 3; 1 2 3; 1 2 3`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @PaulManta , oops sorry forgot a `:` I am using matlab, but this behaviour should be the same, but you should do `v(ones(3,1),:)`

Answer (score 2):

So you have 3D centroids and 3D points, and you want for **any** points **pt** in `points` to determine the distance from all centroids.

```
arrayfun(@(x) norm(x),pt(ones(v,1),:)-centroids)
```